# Adjust multiple line spacing when using mixed fonts with \Centerstack from stackengine

Tags: stackengine

In the following image, I'd like to nudge the line `in the` up just a bit so that it appears vertically centered between the words `Seaweed` and `Ocean`. The `\vspace{-10pt}` macro doesn't seem to do anything to shift the alignment.

[image: Can I nudge "in the" up just a bit?]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\setstackgap{L}{16pt}
\savestack{\restime}{${\Centerstack[r]{{$\emph{Residence}$} {$\emph{Time}$}}}$}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\restime$\left|\Centerstack[l]{\textbf{Seaweed} {\scriptsize \vspace{-10pt}\hspace{7pt}in~the} {\textbf{Ocean}}}\right.$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `\Centerstack` uses a "long stack" that sets a fixed baselineskip between lines.  Because "in the" is a smaller font, it shows more gap above, so as to make up the required baselineskip.  What you were trying to achieve with the `\vspace` can be achieved with a `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\setstackgap{L}{16pt}

\savestack{\restime}{${\Centerstack[r]{{$\emph{Residence}$} {$\emph{Time}$}}}$}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\restime$\left|\Centerstack[l]{\textbf{Seaweed} 
  {\scriptsize\hspace{7pt}\raisebox{1pt}{in~the}} 
  {\textbf{Ocean}}}\right.$
\end{document}
```

[image]